# How to disable keyboard accents on quote (apostrophe) key

Tags: keyboard

I'm Latvian so I'm using the Latvian keyboard layout.

The thing is that the <kbd>'</kbd> (single quote key) was built a long time ago when computers didn't have native Latvian keyboard support.

Modern layouts use <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Opt</kbd> for accents.

Weirdly enough, macOS uses both options. I only use <kbd>Opt</kbd>, but the apostrophe slows me down insanely when writing code.
For the accent, I **hold** <kbd>Opt</kbd> to type, but for the apostrophe, it's 2 taps.

Is there a way to disable it without creating a whole new keyboard layout?

Here's a [video](https://share.cleanshot.com/gV2ztzdS) of how the apostrophe works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case using a custom keyboard layout is ok in the end, it seems that someone made one that does what you want on [GitHub: OS X keyboard layout similar to the Windows "Latvian (QWERTY)" layout.](https://github.com/kristaps/mac-lv-alt-layout).